# Couchbase find() error

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-ottoman, ottoman-node

As per the documentation teaches [here](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/december/easily-develop-node.js-and-couchbase-apps-with-ottoman) under "Reading NoSQL Documents" part.

I copied the exact same code below.

```
UserModel.find({}, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("An error happened -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    // Do something with the resulting Ottoman models
});
```

But it's giving me the error

`TypeError: First argument needs to be a ViewQuery, SpatialQuery or N1qlQuery.`

Why is it producing the error? And what are `ViewQuery`, `SpatialQuery` and `N1qlQuery`?

Comment: "The above would find all documents that were created using the Ottoman UserModel." Have you created documents using your Ottoman UserModal ?

Comment: @AlexisCôté Yes Im pretty sure I have documents on my bucket created using ottoman.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with regard to using different versions of the Couchbase Node.js SDK than Ottoman.js is using internally.  You can either fork Ottoman.js and upgrade the SDK version it is using internally, or you can downgrade your application to match Ottoman.js.  This will be resolved in the next release of the Couchbase Node.js SDK and Ottoman.js (it will allow you to specify which version to use internally).

Comment: Hello Brett. Could you specify the working versions for both couchbase and ottoman? Thanks!